# Can colmap coordinates be converted to gps coordinates?

Tags: gps, coordinates, coordinate-systems, colmap

I have a folder of 20 images and I run colmap on it and I exported the model as a .txt file. I want to convert these colmap poses or coordinates into gps coordinates.

So far I have only exported the poses as I am not very familiar with colmap system yet. Would be awesome if somebody helped me with a hint.

Comment: If you have a location of a single pose, and rest of the poses relative to that pose, you can simply convert the rest of poses to GPS coordinates right? I am not sure why is this confusing. Am I understanding this wrong?

Comment: @Kani Lol, how can you simply convert the poses to gps coordinates is the question.

Comment: What does your pose data look like? I assumed you have the rotation and the position of the camera relative to some common frame, similar to what is defined in ColMap output documentation. If that is not the case, can you add more details to your question?